# how to use feeder like this in gatling

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

i can use feeder like this

```
val feeder_global_2 = Iterator.continually(Map("time"->System.currentTimeMillis()))

  var http_conf_api1424 = http.baseUrls("http://10.156.17.143:9327").disableCaching
  val api1424 = scenario("1424/v1/kol/user/info").during(60){
    feed(feeder_global_2).
      exec(http("0_1424/v1/kol/user/info")
        .post("/v1/kol/user/info")
        .header("Stress-Flag","true")
        .header("time","${uid}")

      )}
```

but when i got a file like this ,how can i use feeder to replace the http path , headers and post body ?

```
{"method":"POST","path":"url1","get":"","post":"xxx=1&.....","header":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip","Content-Length":"118"}}
{"method":"POST","path":"url1","get":"","post":"yyy=1&....","header":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip","Content-Length":"118"}}
{"method":"POST","path":"url1","get":"","post":"xxx=1&....","header":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip","Content-Length":"118"}}
......
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use gatling EL variables in a file by passing an ELFileBody into the .body statement.

So you could update your file to

```
{"method":"POST","path":"${url}","get":"","post":"${body}","header":${headers.jsonStringify()}...
```